# SQL Select set of records from one table, join each record to top 1 record of second table matching 1 column, sorted by a column in the second table

Tags: sql-server

This is my first question on here, so I apologize if I break any rules.

Here's the situation. I have a table that lists all the employees and the building to which they are assigned, plus training hours, with ssn as the id column, I have another table that list all the employees in the company, also with ssn, but including name, and other personal data. The second table contains multiple records for each employee, at different points in time. What I need to do is select all the records in the first table from a certain building, then get the most recent name from the second table, plus allow the result set to be sorted by any of the columns returned.

I have this in place, and it works fine, it is just very slow.
A very simplified version of the tables are:

```
table1 (ssn CHAR(9), buildingNumber CHAR(7), trainingHours(DEC(5,2)) (7200 rows)
table2 (ssn CHAR(9), fName VARCHAR(20), lName VARCHAR(20), sequence INT) (708,000 rows)
```

The sequence column in table 2 is a number that corresponds to a predetermined date to enter these records, the higher number, the more recent the entry. It is common/expected that each employee has several records. But several may not have the most recent(i.e. '8').

My SProc is:

```
@BuildingNumber CHAR(7), @SortField VARCHAR(25)
BEGIN
DECLARE @returnValue TABLE(ssn CHAR(9), buildingNumber CAHR(7), fname VARCHAR(20), lName VARCHAR(20), rowNumber INT)

INSERT INTO @returnValue(...) 
    SELECT(ssn,buildingNum,fname,lname,rowNum)
        FROM SELECT(...,CASE @SortField Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY buildingNumber ORDER BY {sortField column} END AS RowNumber)
           FROM table1 a
               OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 fName,lName FROM table2 WHERE ssn = a.ssn ORDER BY sequence DESC) AS e
           where buildingNumber = @BuildingNumber

SELECT * from @returnValue ORDER BY RowNumber
END
```

I have indexes for the following:

table1: buildingNumber(non-unique,nonclustered)
table2: sequence_ssn(unique,nonclustered)

Like I said this gets me the correct result set, but it is rather slow. Is there a better way to go about doing this?

It's not possible to change the database structure or the way table 2 operates. Trust me if it were it would be done. Are there any indexes I could make that would help speed this up?

I've looked at the execution plans, and it has a clustered index scan on table 2(18%), then a compute scalar(0%), then an eager spool(59%), then a filter(0%), then top n sort(14%).
That's 78% of the execution so I know it's in the section to get the names, just not sure of a better(faster) way to do it.

The reason I'm asking is that table 1 needs to be updated with current data. This is done through a webpage with a radgrid control. It has a range, start index, all that, and it takes forever for the users to update their data.
I can change how the update process is done, but I thought I'd ask about the query first.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would just join the two tables and leverage the rank function.  From there, just select where the ranked column = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this with window functions.  The idea is to assign a sequence number to records in the table with duplicates (I think `table2`), such as the most recent records have a value of 1.  Then just select this as the most recent record:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ssn order by sequence desc) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.ssn = t1.ssn and t2.seqnum = 1
where t1.buildingNumber = @BuildingNumber;
```

My second suggestion is to use a user-defined function rather than a stored procedure:

```
create function XXX (
    @BuildingNumber int
)
returns table as
return (
    select t1.ssn, t1.buildingNum, t2.fname, t2.lname, rowNum
    from table1 t1 join
         (select t2.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by ssn order by sequence desc) as seqnum
          from table2 t2
         ) t2
         on t1.ssn = t1.ssn and t2.seqnum = 1
    where t1.buildingNumber = @BuildingNumber;
);
```

(This doesn't have the logic for the ordering because that doesn't seem to be the central focus of the question.)

You can then call it as:

```
select *
from dbo.XXX(<building number>);
```

EDIT:

The following may speed it up further, because you are only selecting a small(ish) subset of the employees:

```
select *
from (select t1.*, t2.*,  row_number() over (partition by ssn order by sequence desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1 join
           table2 t2
           on t1.ssn = t1.ssn
      where t1.buildingNumber = @BuildingNumber
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

And, finally, I suspect that the following might be the fastest:

```
select t1.*, t2.*,  row_number() over (partition by ssn order by sequence desc) as seqnum
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.ssn = t1.ssn
where t1.buildingNumber = @BuildingNumber and
      t2.sequence = (select max(sequence) from table2 t2a where t2a.ssn = t1.ssn)
```

In all these cases, an index on `table2(ssn, sequence)` should help performance.

Comment: That decreased the time by about half, but it's still way too slow for what it's doing. It's taking 3 seconds per read even on the smaller buildings. Any other suggestions or is this about as good as I can hope to get? I should probably just bite the bullet and accept having to rewrite this and work with the Telerik garbage.

Comment: Those all work, but there's a lot more complication in it which makes wierd things happen. I'll definitely use what you've given me here and tweak it to work. I've got until next year at this time to get it ironed out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some temp tables instead of the table variables.  Not sure what kind of system you are working on, but I have had pretty good luck.  Temp tables actually write to the drive so you wont be holding and processing so much in memory.  Depending on other system usage this might do the trick.

Simple define the temp table using #Tablename instead of @Tablename.  Put the name sorting subquery in a temp table before everything else fires off and make a join to it.

Just make sure to drop the table at the end.  It will drop the table at the end of the SP when it disconnects, but it is a good idea to make tell it to drop to be on the safe side.