# How to select all records from first table and only first matching record from second table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

From this two tables

```
FirstTable
Number|
  1   |
  2   |
  3   |
  4   |

SecondTable
Id | Number | Column2 | Column3
--------------------------------
1  |  1     | text1   | text11
2  |  2     | text2   | text12
3  |  3     | text3   | text13
4  |  3     | text4   | text14
5  |  2     | text5   | text15
```

How to select all records from first table and only first matching record from second table with nulls?
Result should be like this:

```
Result
Number | Column2 | Column3
--------------------------
 1     | text1   | text11
 2     | text2   | text12
 3     | text3   | text13
 4     | null    | null
```

I tried:

```
SELECT FT.Number, ST.Column2, ST.Column3
FROM FirstTable FT LEFT JOIN 
SecondTable ST ON FT.Number = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 S2.Number FROM SecondTable S2 WHERE S2.Number = FT.Number
)
```

or

```
SELECT min(FT.Number), ST.Column2, ST.Column3
FROM FirstTable FT LEFT JOIN 
SecondTable ST ON FT.Number = ST.Number
GROUP BY ST.Column2, ST.Column3
```

Comment: Does SecondTable have a column with unique values in it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Select set of records from one table, join each record to top 1 record of second table matching 1 column, sorted by a column in the second table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822480/sql-select-set-of-records-from-one-table-join-each-record-to-top-1-record-of-se)

Comment: I edited, yes it have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with Row_Number() in a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT T1.Number, T2.Column1, T2.Column3 
FROM FirstTable T1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ID, NUMBER, Colunmn2, Column3,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY ID ASC) as NumOrder
            FROM SecondTable
) T2 ON T1.Number = T2.Number AND T2.NumOrder = 1
```

If you run just the sub-query you will see how this works -- it "flags" the rows of interest by having a value of 1.  Then a simple join works.

Comment: This is pretty much the answer from the cited duplicate.

Comment: @TabAlleman - oh.  heh.  Didn't read that.  It is the way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this variation of your first attempt:

```
SELECT FT.Number, ST.Column2, ST.Column3
FROM FirstTable FT LEFT JOIN 
SecondTable ST ON ST.Id = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 S2.Id FROM SecondTable S2 WHERE S2.Number = FT.Number
    ORDER BY S2.Id
)
```

EDIT:

I ran the following script as a test:

```
DECLARE @FirstTable TABLE (
  [Number] int
);

DECLARE @SecondTable TABLE (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1)
,   Number int
,   Column2 varchar(31)
,   Column3 varchar(31)
)

INSERT INTO @FirstTable (Number) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);

INSERT INTO @SecondTable (Number, Column2, Column3) VALUES
    (1, 'text1', 'text11')
,   (2, 'text2', 'text12')
,   (3, 'text3', 'text13')
,   (3, 'text4', 'text14')
,   (2, 'text5', 'text15')
;

SELECT FT.Number, ST.Column2, ST.Column3
FROM @FirstTable FT LEFT JOIN 
@SecondTable ST ON ST.Id = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 S2.Id FROM @SecondTable S2 WHERE S2.Number = FT.Number
    ORDER BY S2.Id
);
```

And I got the following results:

```
Number  Column2 Column3
1           text1   text11
2           text2   text12
3           text3   text13
4           NULL    NULL
```

Which is exactly your desired result.   If you are getting "too many rows" you must have made a mistake in the implementation.

Comment: Not possible with my query, but if this is a simplification of a more complicated query, then the problem could exist in a part of the query you aren't showing.

Comment: 1 text1 text11
1 text2 text12
1 text3 text13
1 text4 text14
1 text5 text15
2 text1 text11
2 text2 text12
2 text3 text13
2 text4 text14
2 text5 text15
3 text1 text11
3 text2 text12
3 text3 text13
3 text4 text14
3 text5 text15
4 NULL NULL

Comment: I can't follow your comment in that format, but see my edit.