# How to Join tables to assign one record to multiple records in a "FIFO" order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to assign multiple records from one table to single records from the second table until the quantity is met. I'm using MS SQL 2012.

We have this External Invoice table

**ExtInvoice**

```
+-------------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+
| Ext_Invoice | P_No | Part | InvoiceDate | Due_Date | NumOrder |
+-------------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+
|         571 |  607 | 7991 |      151116 |   151222 |        1 |
|         572 |  607 | 7991 |      151120 |   151228 |        2 |
|         573 |  607 | 7991 |      151127 |   160104 |        3 |
+-------------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+
```

**InternalInvoice**

```
+------------+----------+------+------+-----+----------+
| Invoice_No | Original | P_No | Part | Qty | NumOrder |
+------------+----------+------+------+-----+----------+
|        198 | 607      |  607 | 7991 |   2 |        1 |
|        199 | RE607    |  607 | 7991 |   1 |        2 |
|        200 | RE607    |  607 | 7991 |   1 |        3 |
+------------+----------+------+------+-----+----------+
```

The results is to assign the first 2 records from the `ExtInvoice` to the first record in the `InternalInvoice` and the remainder should go to the second `InternalInvoice` record.  Each line in the `ExtInvoice` represents one `Quantity`.

The `NumOrder` is not unique because this was a `ROW_Number` SQL Calculation.

*The desired results are :*

[image]

There are obviously more invoices in the tables but this is the part where it's not working. There are temp tables with row_number() manipulation to get to the tables ExtInvoice, InternalInvoice. I actually used this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841838/how-to-select-all-records-from-first-table-and-only-first-matching-record-from-s)

I am currently using

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM InternalInvoice AS R      
 JOIN ExtInvoice AS S
   ON S.P_No=R.P_No
   AND S.Part=R.Part
   AND  R.Qty>=S.NumOrder
```

This is what I am getting. I tried a lot of different ways but looks like I am stuck now. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Sorry for the images link, it seems I do not have the reputation yet to directly link the images. I will change them back when I get enough rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate running sum of `Qty` to know how many rows to skip from `ExtInvoice` using

```
SUM(Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY P_No ORDER BY NumOrder)
```

Use `OUTER APPLY` to join tables and pick the number of rows defined by `Qty` in `TOP`.

**Sample data**

I added one more `P_No` to verify that results are partitioned correctly.

```
DECLARE @ExtInvoice TABLE 
(Ext_Invoice int, P_No int, Part int, InvoiceDate int, Due_Date int, NumOrder int);

INSERT INTO @ExtInvoice
(Ext_Invoice, P_No, Part, InvoiceDate, Due_Date, NumOrder)
VALUES
(571, 607, 7991, 151116, 151222, 1),
(572, 607, 7991, 151120, 151228, 2),
(573, 607, 7991, 151127, 160104, 3),
(574, 608, 7991, 151127, 160104, 1);


DECLARE @InternalInvoice TABLE
(Invoice_No int, Original varchar(5), P_No int, Part int, Qty int, NumOrder int);

INSERT INTO @InternalInvoice
(Invoice_No, Original, P_No, Part, Qty, NumOrder)
VALUES
(198, '607', 607, 7991, 2, 1),
(199, 'RE607', 607, 7991, 1, 2),
(200, 'RE607', 607, 7991, 1, 3),
(201, 'RE608', 608, 7991, 1, 1);
```

**Query**

I the final query you should list actual column names instead of `*`.
To make it work efficiently there should be an index for `ExtInvoice` table on `(P_No, NumOrder)`.

```
WITH
CTE_InternalInvoices
AS
(
    SELECT
        I.*
        ,SUM(Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY P_No ORDER BY NumOrder) AS SumQty
    FROM
        @InternalInvoice AS I
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE_InternalInvoices
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(CTE_InternalInvoices.Qty) *
        FROM @ExtInvoice AS E
        WHERE
            E.P_No = CTE_InternalInvoices.P_No
            AND E.NumOrder > CTE_InternalInvoices.SumQty - CTE_InternalInvoices.Qty
        ORDER BY E.NumOrder
    ) AS CA
ORDER BY CTE_InternalInvoices.Invoice_No;
```

**Result**

```
+------------+----------+------+------+-----+----------+--------+-------------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+
| Invoice_No | Original | P_No | Part | Qty | NumOrder | SumQty | Ext_Invoice | P_No | Part | InvoiceDate | Due_Date | NumOrder |
+------------+----------+------+------+-----+----------+--------+-------------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+
|        198 | 607      |  607 | 7991 |   2 |        1 |      2 | 571         | 607  | 7991 | 151116      | 151222   | 1        |
|        198 | 607      |  607 | 7991 |   2 |        1 |      2 | 572         | 607  | 7991 | 151120      | 151228   | 2        |
|        199 | RE607    |  607 | 7991 |   1 |        2 |      3 | 573         | 607  | 7991 | 151127      | 160104   | 3        |
|        200 | RE607    |  607 | 7991 |   1 |        3 |      4 | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL        | NULL     | NULL     |
|        201 | RE608    |  608 | 7991 |   1 |        1 |      1 | 574         | 608  | 7991 | 151127      | 160104   | 1        |
+------------+----------+------+------+-----+----------+--------+-------------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d6954dd72e53b90/90/0)